# how can i get main folder name inside root folder while copying all files to source to destination

Tags: bash, shell, file, unix

i have folders inside input_scan but i need folder1 and folder3 beacuse they are super folders for 5.txt,1.txt and 2.txt. how can i get this? with the current code i am getting folder1 for 5.txt, folder2 for 1.txt and folder7 for 2.txt

```
Ex:
input_scan
 /folder1
   /5.txt
   /folder2
     /1.txt
 /folder3
  /folder4
   /folder5
    /folder6
      /folder7
       /2.txt
```

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        parent_dir=$(basename "$(dirname "$file")")
        echo $parent_dir
    fi
done < <(find "input_scan" -type f -print0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU utils.

```
find "input_scan" -type f -print0 | cut -zd'/' -f2 | sort -zu
```

---

If it is a shell loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A uniq
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  dir=${file#*/}
  ((uniq["${dir%%/*}"]++))
done < <(find "input_scan" -type f -print0)
printf '%s\n' "${!uniq[@]}"
```

---

Since there is no need to count the directories, we can change

```
((uniq["${dir%%/*}"]++))
```

To:

```
uniq["${dir%%/*}"]=
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for d in input_scan/*/; do
    if find "$d" -type f -print -quit | grep -q .; then
        basename "$d"
    fi
done
```

Run `find` on each candidate path in `input_scan/*/`. If any files found, print its basename (trailing slashes are ignored).

`-quit` option to find improves efficiency - no need to keep searching the tree once any match is found.

---

It is not clear what the desired condition is - sample code suggests simple existence of any files inside a (sub)directory. If this is not the only condition, extra clauses can be added to the find command (eg. `-name '*.txt'`)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ find ./input_scan -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "%P\n"|sed 's/\/.*//'|uniq
folder1
folder3
```